# Finding Shortcuts in Aptana Studio 3.0 to Comment Code

Tags: ide, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I can't find any shortcuts for comment my code in Aptana Studio 3.0. I need shortcuts both to comment individual lines and for commenting selected blocks of code.

Some have told me to try to comment with shortcut `WIN + /` on my Windows OS but that does not appear workable.

Comment: Have you found it already?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope. In Aptana for Linux it works. Now I use OSX and Textmate :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on which language you're writing in (is this CSS, Javascript, HTML?)

For Javascript:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> to add or remove // for a single line of code, or for multiple selected lines.

The standard Java commenting shortcuts are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> to add/remove // for a single line of code, or for multiple selected lines.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> to add /* */ around selected code.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to add Javadoc comments.

You can always find out shortcuts by hitting Ctrl-shift-l, which will bring up a list of all currently available shortcuts. They will change depending on if you have anything selected, what type of file you're editing, etc. Look for "Add comments", "Toggle block comments", "Toggle JS comments", and so forth.

Comment: Nice answer, but in my Aptana I only have comments for PyDev... Any shortcuts for comments don't exists :( I have downloaded Aptana from official site - why my IDE hasn't this shortcuts?

Comment: Have you installed PyDev as a separate plugin? Are you writing PHP files or HTML, or something else?

Comment: Yes, PyDev is installed. I don't know how - as separate or something else...

Comment: For what it's worth, while CTRL-SHIFT-L brings up a list of shortcuts commenting out shortcuts aren't listed (CTRL-SHIFT-/ and CTRL-/).  At least, not for PHP.

Comment: For anyone asking themselves why command+7 does not work on mac go to preferences->general->keys and select "toggle js comments" and make sure that "Javascript editor scope" is selected!!! This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 34):

I was having the same problem, looks like the keyboard makes the shortcut Shift-Ctrl-/ and similar ones completely useless (for the slash character) and Aptana does not allow you to change those shortcuts.

I used **Ctrl-7** and works for any type of code you are selecting, if you want to un-comment  just repeat the command.

Comment: Wow, amazing that this question and top answers were posted a year ago, and you just now you posted your answer -- amazing because I just now had this problem and the top answers didn't work for me, but this does (if I had had this problem yesterday instead I'd be out of luck). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This worked for ruby code. FYI its Cmd-7 on Macs yo!

Comment: +1, how intuitive, should have known ctrl-7 would the obvious comment line(s) shortcut

Comment: The problem is that it is not block comment, and  ctrl+shift+7, at least in my Aptana 3.4.1 over PC or Mac, doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Check Commands > Source > Comments. A number of shortcuts are listed there.

Comment: nice, but i can only click it, they don't work on keyboard :(

Comment: What version of Aptana Studio are you using, and is on on a foreign-language keyboard? The 3.0.3 release added some extra commands for toggling comments, which may work for you.