# What is the shortcut to comment multiple lines with /* ... */ in Aptana Studio 3 on Mac?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, comments, aptana

Here are the few shortcuts to comment code, which works great on Windows.

- Ctrl-/ to add or remove // for a single line of code, or for multiple selected lines
- Ctrl-/ to add/remove // for a single line of code, or for multiple selected lines
- Ctrl-shift-/ to add /* */ around selected code

The Mac alternative of the Ctrl-/ is Command-/

**What is the Mac alternative of the Ctrl-shift-/ for Mac?**

Related Question: [Finding Shortcuts in Aptana Studio 3.0 to Comment Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961478/shortcuts-in-aptana-studio-3-0-to-comment-code)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check Commands > Source > Comments. A number of shortcuts are listed there.

Answer (score 10):

On Mac, you search for <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
The shortcut generates multi line comments with `//`.

Answer (score 2):

// for a single line of code(L for Line)

```
Alt + C + L
```

/* */ around selected code(B for Block)

```
Alt + C + B
```

Answer (score 1):

VScode multiple line comments on Mac `/*  */`

```
shift + option + a
```

VScode single line comment on Mac `//`

```
command + /
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the Code to Comment.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.